# 'show parameter processes' query not working in oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle

i am using oracle 10g database express edition.When i am trying to execute "show parameter processes" query in oracle it is not working.
it shows an error message :

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

But 'show parameter processes' query executed successfully in sqlplus.

my problem is : i am connecting with oracle database using vb.net application. I need to execute this query in this application.

i have a code:

```
            Dim sql As String = "Show parameter processes" 
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
            Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

it gives compilation error : "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

can any one help me please.

Answer (score 6):

"Show parameter XX" is a SQLPLUS command.

the equivalent in SQL is (which is what SQLPLUS will do behind the curtains for you)

```
select value from v$parameter where name LIKE '%processes%'
```